# Getting unique values from lists(containing tags) in dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list inside my dataframe, here is an example:

```
   movieId                     title                        genres
0        1                 Toy Story  [Animation, Comedy, Fantasy]
1        2                   Jumanji          [Adventure, Fantasy]
2        3          Grumpier Old Men             [Comedy, Romance]
3        4         Waiting to Exhale      [Comedy, Drama, Romance]
```

How can I get the list with unique items from the lists in this row? Does Pandas provide a fast built-in method to do this without using loops.

output can be:

```
[Animation, Comedy, Fantasy, Adventure, Romance, Drama]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***method 1***
`pd.DataFrame` and `set`

```
set(pd.DataFrame(df.genres.tolist()).stack().tolist())
```

***method 2***
custom function `box` + `set`

```
def box(l):
    lengths = [len(item) for item in l]
    shape = (len(l), max(lengths))
    a = np.full(shape, None, dtype=object)
    for i, r in enumerate(l):
        a[i, :lengths[i]] = r
    return a

set(box(df.genres.tolist()).ravel().tolist())
```

---

***timing***
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chain` from `itertools` to flatten nested list and use `set` to get the unique values:

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain.from_iterable(df.genres))
# {'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Romance'}
```

Or another `pandas` solution:

```
df.genres.apply(pd.Series).stack().drop_duplicates().tolist()
# ['Animation', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Adventure', 'Romance', 'Drama']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a set and update it with a simple traversal of the Series:

```
unique_items = set()

df.genres.apply(unique_items.update)

unique_items
Out[66]: {'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Romance'}
```